# Prepend CDN url to mvc 4 bundler output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, bundling-and-minification

Using the built in MVC4 bundler, how do I prepend my CDN url to the link tags it produces?  I've setup Amazon Cloudfront so that it pulls assets from my webserver when first requested.  So when I define a bundle like so:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/reset.css",
    "~/Content/960_24_col.css",
    "~/Content/Site.css"
 ));
```

When deployed, I can reference it thus:

```
http://[cloundfrontid].cloudfront.net/Content/css?v=muhFMZ4thy_XV3dMI2kPt-8Rljm5PNW0tHeDkvenT0g1
```

Now I just need to change the links produced by the bundler from being relative to absolute links pointing to my CDN.

```
  <link href="[INSERT_CDN_URL_HERE]/Content/css?v=muhFMZ4thy_XV3dMI2kPt-8Rljm5PNW0tHeDkvenT0g1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I think it may be possible to rewrite the path using IBundleTransform but I can't find any examples of this.

NOTE:
Just to be clear, I know you can specify a CDN link for a bundle, but that only works if the bundle can be replaced by a static link.

Comment: Why can't you use a static link to your CDN?

Comment: because I don't know what that link will be at compile time.  The bundler assigns it dynamically with a cache busting string e.g. /Content/css?v=muhFMZ4thy_XV3dMI2kPt-8Rljm5PNW0tHeDkvenT0g1

Comment: Your CDN is actually using the query string to switch on what content it gives back?  Couldn't you just hardcode the versions explicitly into your CDN? i.e. /content/css1 and just bump it each time you rev your bundles?

Comment: I see what you're saying: control the cache busting myself by manually setting the query string.  Makes sense.  Ideally I'd like to completely automate the deployment process as that's the kind of thing I'd forget to increment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just setup MaxCDN and ran into the same exact issue.

As you know, the `bundles.UseCdn` property is not ideal because we don't want to have to specify the exact url for the bundle. A CDN like Max CDN is the same exact url, query string and all, except for a different subdomain.

Here is how I ended up solving it.

I created a `BundleHelper` class that will wrap the render method and then prepend the path with the CDN subdomain.

Here is what the class looks like:

```
namespace MyDomain.Web.Helpers
{
    public class BundleHelper
    {
        public static string CdnPath = "http://cdn.mydomain.com";

        public static IHtmlString RenderScript(string path)
        {
            var opt = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(path);
            string htmlString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(opt.ToHtmlString());

            if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
            {
                htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<script src=\"/", String.Format("<script src=\"{0}/", CdnPath));
            }

            return new HtmlString(htmlString);
        }

        public static IHtmlString RenderStyle(string path)
        {
            var opt = System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(path);
            string htmlString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(opt.ToHtmlString());

            if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
            {
                htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<link href=\"/", String.Format("<link href=\"{0}/", CdnPath));
            }

            return new HtmlString(htmlString);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it in the views, I simply do:

```
@BundleHelper.RenderStyle("~/Content/css")
@BundleHelper.RenderStyle("~/Content/themes/base/css")

@BundleHelper.RenderScript("~/bundles/jquery")
@BundleHelper.RenderScript("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't tried it but this looks like a good solution.  In the end I went with the solution outlined [on my blog](http://www.peteg.eu/blog/2013/03/15/using-mvc4-bundler-with-a-content-delivery-network/).  I'll mark yours as the accepted because it's more efficient.

Comment: Hello BigJoe: I also want to prepend cdn url to bundler output..and I have done the same as you have described, I did not understand what you have done in ViewPages. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look @ [Using a CDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) search for "Using a CDN"

> As said by By Rick Anderson in asp.net/mvc,
>
> The follow code replaces the local jQuery bundle with a CDN jQuery
>   bundle.

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
    }
```

> In the code above, jQuery will be requested from the CDN while in
>   release mode  and  the debug version of jQuery will be fetched locally
>   in debug mode. When using a CDN, you should have a fallback mechanism
>   in case the CDN request fails. The following markup fragment from the
>   end of the layout file shows script added to request jQuery should the
>   CDN fail.

```
    </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.src = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")';
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);

            }
        </script> 

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

In have pasted the section from Asp.net/MVC, in case you find it useful then Cheers to Rick Anderson for his post...

Comment: Ooops its a Feb,12 post :)